# What genre would a fictional eyewitness account of a real historical event fall under?

Tags: fiction, short-story, genre, historical-fiction, historical

I've written a short story about a true historical incident which involves a very famous person in history. The incident is true as are the people involved in it. But the story is a fictional eyewitness narrative of that incident from a person who was not mentioned in it, but could have been one of the principal witnesses.

What genre does this story fall under?

It can't be Alternate History because the narrative mentions an incident which actually happened.

Could it be Historical? Could be termed as Biographical?

Comment: You should read Flashman (1969) by George MacDonald Fraser, the first of the Flashman series, in which the "memoirs" of the fictional schoolboy bully from Tom Brown's Schooldays (1857) tell of his involvement in many famous 19th century historical events.  Fraser includes notes where he compares the statements from "Flashman's "memoirs" with the historical record to check their "accuracy".  There is a scene in the retreat from Kabul where Fraser inserts Flashman into a scene with a Indian child that a surviving officer mentioned in his memoirs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Historical Fiction. Off the top of my head . . . it keeps company with Shakespeare in Love, Titanic, Murder in the First, The Other Boleyn Girl, and a host of others.

I must give a shout out to "Krakatoa, East of Java" - who cares about accuracy!